# Replace dates which are read by R as factors with 1 and blank values with 0

Tags: r

I have an R data frame where the date column in read as factor by R. This column has blank values where dates are not available.
I wanted to replace the dates read by R as factors with 1 and the blank values with 0.

What I have is something like following:

```
Date
1-Jul-08

1-Sep-14


1-Jul-17
1-Jun-16
```

What I want to get to is like following:

```
Date
1
0
1
0
0
1
1
```

Appreciate any help.
Thanks

Comment: What does `levels(Date)` give you?

Comment: It gives me list of 254 levels. Something like this: [1] ""          "1-Apr-17"  "1-Aug-17"  "1-Dec-16"  "1-Feb-17"  "1-Jun-17"

Comment: `new_Data <- (Date == Date[2]) - 1`, since the 2nd element is a blank.

Comment: Perfect! It replaced blanks with TRUE and factors as FALSE. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, it worked like a charm. Thanks Headpoint :)

Answer (score 0):

`ifelse` can be useful here. Try this

```
df <- data.frame(Date = c("1-Jul-08", "", "1-Sep-14", "", "", "1-Jul-17", "1-Jun-16"))
df$Date <- ifelse(df$Date == "", 0, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this it simply checks if there are characters in your date it will putt it 1 else 0

```
   x[["Dates"]] = ifelse(nchar(x[["Dates"]]) > 0,
                           x[["Dates"]]<-1),
                           x[["Time_.EST."]]<-0)
```